# Overriding a method returning typename T does not work

Tags: c++, templates, overriding

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        OverrideMe();
    }
    virtual ~A(){};

    virtual T OverrideMe()
    {
        throw string("A.OverrideMe called");
    }

protected:

    T member;
};

class B : public A<double>
{
public:
    B(){};
    virtual ~B(){};

    virtual double OverrideMe()
    {
        throw string("B.OverrideMe called");
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        B b;
    }
    catch(string s)
    {
        cout << s << endl; //this prints: A.OverrideMe called
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do? What does it do currently?

Comment: The methods are protected, so you can't actually call them from main. This is not the code you are running.

Comment: Here - http://ideone.com/W2H9ZD - it prints `B.OverrideMe called`. What is your compiler ?

Comment: @juanchopanza, Thanks for noticing, I can't paste the real code, but this is close enough.

Comment: Again, [works with pure](http://ideone.com/84fF7A).

Comment: @chris, I want the OverrideMe method to behave differently in the speciallized A<double> instance.

Comment: I call BS: http://ideone.com/ruvy3O

Comment: @GalGoldman, And that's exactly what's happening in the code you posted, except there isn't really any `A<double>` instance. If you want the same effect from an `A` object, specialize `A`.

Comment: Weird. OK guys, thanks. I'll have a better look on what's the difference in my code.

Comment: Why do you derive from A ? Maybe you want to **specialize** A ? Like this - http://ideone.com/9Z1qFl

Comment: Name your compiler. Works in VS 2010. Post a test case you have actually run.

Comment: Try making the `A` method pure virtual and see what happens in your code. Does it still compile?

Comment: Guys, I have now edited the code to match my real code and now it does what I claimed it did, calling A's OverrideMe() rather than B's OverrideMe(). I now also understand why this happed, it's because I am calling a virtual method from A's C'tor, which I shouldn't do... :-( Thanks for all the help and sorry the code I pasted in the beginning was not accurate and failed to demonstrate the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can override a method from a template base class, as can be shown in this example:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
  virtual T foo() const {
    std::cout << "Foo::foo()\n";
    return T();
  }
};

struct Bar : Foo<double>
{
  virtual double foo() const {
    std::cout << "Bar::foo()\n";
    return 3.14;
  }
};

int main(){
  Bar b;
  double x = b.foo();
}
```

output:

> Bar::foo()

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting (out of the blue) that your type `T` is declared but not defined.